# Python stdout during multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, stdout

I'm running a scrape on a website and I would like to print out a counter to show progress. I had this working during serial processing. (It's a two step scrape)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from sys import stdout
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

global searched_counter,processed_counter
searched_counter = 0
processed_counter = 0

def run_scrape(var_input):
    global searched_counter,processed_counter
    #get search results
    parsed = #parse using bs4

    searched_counter += 1
    stdout.write("\rTotal Searched/Processed: %d/%d" % (searched_counter,processed_counter))
    stdout.flush()

    if parsed:       #only go to next page if result is what I want
        #get the page I want using parsed data
        #parse some more and write out to file

        processed_counter += 1
        stdout.write("\rTotal Searched/Processed: %d/%d" % (searched_counter,processed_counter))
        stdout.flush()    


list_to_scrape = ["data%05d" % (x,) for x in range(1,10000)]
pool = Pool(8)
pool.map(run_scrape,list_to_scrape)

stdout.write('\n')
```

When I run it with multiprocessing, it goes haywire and prints a lot of random numbers that don't add up to what it's actually writing to the file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal Python variable can't be shared between processes, so each worker process in your pool ends up with its own copy of `searched_counter` and `processed_counter`, so incrementing them in one process won't have any affect on the others. The `multiprocessing` library has [a few ways to share state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), but the easiest one for your use-case is to use a [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from sys import stdout

def init(s, p):
    global searched_counter, processed_counter
    searched_counter = s
    processed_counter = p

def run_scrape(var_input):
    global searched_counter, processed_counter
    #get search results
    parsed = #parse using bs4

    with searched_counter.get_lock():
        searched_counter.value += 1
    stdout.write("\rTotal Searched/Processed: %d/%d" % 
                    (searched_counter.value, processed_counter.value))
    stdout.flush()

    if parsed:
        with processed_counter.get_lock():
            processed_counter.value += 1
        stdout.write("\rTotal Searched/Processed: %d/%d" % 
                        (searched_counter.value, processed_counter.value))
        stdout.flush()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    searched_counter = Value('i', 0)
    processed_counter = Value('i', 0)

    list_to_scrape = ["data%05d" % (x,) for x in range(1,10000)]
    pool = Pool(8, initializer=init, initargs=(searched_counter, processed_counter))
    pool.map(run_scrape, list_to_scrape)

    stdout.write('\n')
```

Note that I explicitly pass the counters from the parent to the child processes using the `initializer`/`initargs` keyword arguments, which is a [best practice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms) and helps ensure Windows compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Split the list into groups of some size (n) (possible make a multiple of number in pool), and then iterate through that superlist, making a new pool for each one. You can count as you iterate through the superlist.